# URL Rewriting adding slash at the end breaks my css links

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using Apache mod_rewrite to rewrite my url's in a PHP application.
I have a login.php in my application root.
I wrote the following lines in .htaccess file (I'm using HTML5 boilerplate's htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule  ^signin/?$  login.php
</IfModule>
```

adding a slash at the end of the name **^signin/?$** broke all the css links of this page.

I'm using relative links for css there such as:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'm very new to URL rewriting and htaccess stuff, since i'm learning all this i would love to know why is this behavior occurring?

Comment: Have you tried absolute url?
`<link href="/css/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet">` 
What do you mean when you say it broke the css links?

Comment: when i say broke the links, it means none of the css file was loaded except  html. Actually I've developed the whole app using such links, now a change means changing all the files which is shitt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to have a new redirect rule to remove trailing slash and then your css/js would not be a problem:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apx/

# remove trailing slash from non-directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^signin/?$ login.php [L,NC]
```

However also consider using absolute paths for css/js e.g.

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or else you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/apx/" />
```

Comment: this rule is already present in boilerplate's htaccess :
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

It didn't worked

Comment: apx is my site name all the folders resides inside it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84491/discussion-between-anubhava-and-subhan-ahmed).

Comment: Check updated answer and if you still have issues join the chat link I sent.

Answer (score 4):

When your browser goes to `http://example.com/signin/` the relative base URI becomes `/signin/`. This means **every relative link** in the content of that entire page will have `/signin/` appended to it as the URL base. The original link was just `/login.php`, which makes the base URI `/`. Your browser doesn't know anything about your rewrite rules, just what it sees in the location bar.

You need to change all your links to absolute URLs (with a leading `/`) or specify a relative base URI in the page's header (inside the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: In my login.php i have two kind of bases. one is css/style.css and other is dashboard/somefile.css so what should be the base?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed What is the root-relative URL-path to your CSS files?

Comment: in root i have css which have css files plus i have dashboard which further have css folder

Comment: @SubhanAhmed in all those cases, the base URI is **still** just `/`.

Comment: but this <base href="/" /> is making no difference in my case

Comment: I gave this a +1 because it *explains* why the issue happens.  While the solution is a lot of work for an existing website, it still is a correct solution and should help for planning a new website.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<base href="base link" />` This will set the base of `links`,`img` basically everything. This will fix the links. Example: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Yes. This should be on top of everything in the head. As it sets the 'base' of the paths.

Comment: In my login.php i have two kind of bases. one is css/style.css and other is dashboard/somefile.css so what should be the base?

Comment: You use relative paths now, so it works by making this base: `<base href="/" />